# how to find the next lower 5 levels tile coordinates using quadtree

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, quadtree

This is with reference to Map tiling using quadtree.

Client will give (highest zoom level, row, column)

Could you please let me know how to find the next lower 5 levels tile coordinates

(zoom level, row, column )??

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with row, col and zoom level you can easily determine the tiles in the next zoom level. When a zoom level changes a single tile is broken up into 4 tiles. If the zoom level increases by one then there are twice as many tile rows and columns. So to get the 4 tiles that a tile broke up into you can easily calculate this as this:

tile1: row*2, col*2
tile2: row*2+1, col*2
tile3: row*2, col*2+1
tile4: row*2+1, col*2+1

We would also know that the zoom level = zoom+1. Using this information you can then calculate the quadkey values for each tile using the code documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Comment: My method is based on the Mercator projection which is used by Bing Maps. Not sure why you voted down on this. This is a proven method which I've used many times before. Also, I have 7 years experience working with the Quadkey tree in Bing Maps. I'm on the Bing Maps team :)

Comment: The quadkey tree is pretty simple. Each zoom level is twice the size as the zoom level before it. So if you had the row, col and zoom level of a tile and wanted to know the four tiles it broke up into on the next zoom level then you could simply multiple the row and col value by 2 to get the first tile. The next three will be one tile right, one tile down and one tile left+right. This is all based on this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Comment: For example, take tile with quadkey "2" as shown in that document. This is in row 1, col 0, and zoom 1. At zoom level 2 we can use the formulas I provided to calculate the tiles. tile1: row 2, col 0, tile2: row 3, col 0, tile3: row 2, col 1, tile4: row 3, col 1. And the zoom level would be 2. If you look at the image example in the documentation.

Comment: Correct, you start at the upper left corner. This will work with most other map API's that use the same quad tree tile schema. Note that some mapping API's use X, Y Z instead of a quadkey value to identify tiles. X = Col, Y = Row, Z = zoom level

Comment: Once you have the tile col, row and zoom information the quadkey value can be easily calculated using the code provided in the documentation I mentioned earlier.

Comment: My numbering aligns with the numbering in the documentation I provided.